# How to calculate perplexity of language model?

Tags: nlp

In one of the [lecture on language modeling](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/nlp/slides/languagemodeling.pdf) about calculating the perplexity of a model by Dan Jurafsky in his [course on Natural Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/NLPCourseraSlides.html), in slide number 33 he give the formula for perplexity as

[image]

Then, in the next slide number 34, he presents a following scenario:

"If a system has to recognize
• Operator (1 in 4)
• Sales (1 in 4)
• Technical Support (1 in 4) 
• 30,000 names (1 in 120,000 each)"

Perplexity in this case is 53.

Can anyone explain how the answer 53 came ?

Comment: Could you please share the code for perplexity in python as to how to compare 2 models in text generation task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe he meant: you need to identify/predict a sequence of 4 consecutive things. First: an operator, then a sales person, then a technical support person, and finally one name out of 30,000 names. One and only one sequence is correct.

The probability of the correct sequence:

$$(1/4)*(1/4)*(1/4)*(1/120,000) = 0.0000001302083333$$

If you get the 4th root, that gives you the geometric mean (in some sense that's the average per step for four steps)

$$(0.0000001302083333)^.25 = 0.01899589214 ≈ (1/53)$$

So:

$$(1/53)*(1/53)*(1/53)*(1/53) ≈ (1/4)*(1/4)*(1/4)*(1/120,000)$$

It was however, not clear in the slides or the explanation.